# Spark session with .master("yarn"): addFile(...) does not upload file to executor nodes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark session (client mode, with `.master("yarn")`). I have a file that I need to upload to each Spark executor's file system.

I've uploaded the file to HDFS, created a Spark session (to "/tmp/dummy.txt"), and tried to

I'm creating a SparkSession,and call:

- `SparkSession.addFiles("hdfs:///tmp/dummy.txt")`
- `SparkFiles.get("dummy.txt")`.

And this `SparkFiles.get("dummy.txt")` gives me a path to some folder in `/tmp/spark-blablalba-hash/userFiles-blablabla-hash/dummy.txt`. Such path **does not exist on my Spark executors**, but... does exist on my Spark driver (where I don't need it at all).

How can it be fixed and how can I finally copy the file from driver to executors?

P.S. Some code that I did to get such strange behaviour:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkFiles

if __name__ == "__main__":

    spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport()\
        .master("yarn").getOrCreate()

    # I have uploaded a file "dummy.txt" to HDFS (to hdfs:///tmp/dummy.txt)
    # I want this file from HDFS to be copied to all executors.
    spark.sparkContext.addFile("hdfs:///tmp/dummy.txt")

    # Let's look where it was uploaded...
    path_on_exectors = SparkFiles.get("dummy.txt")
    print(path_on_exectors)

    # > '/tmp/spark-6e61ed03-6866-4863-adb6-b7345836caf3/userFiles-28d28f93-e4df-44c3-a1e5-7411d02d4cf5/dummy.txt'
    # This path was created on my driver node but DOES NOT EXIST on my executors.
    # What can I do to fix it?

    # (Quitting programming, moving to Somalia and becoming a pirate is not an option yet).
```

Comment: For spark on yarn, you may want to use `spark.yarn.dist.files` option, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#spark-properties

Comment: I've tried passing my filename into `'spark.yarn.dist.files'` config parameter when creating my Spark session (by adding `.config("spark.yarn.dist.files", "/path/to/dummy/folder/on/spark/drver/dummy.txt")`)

 -- but it does not create any file on Spark Executors (I call `SparkFiles.get('dummy.txt')` and see that the path that it returns is not created on my executors.

Comment: why are you passing files as part of spark.. you can directly put in hdfs & access it directly ?

Comment: I have to use Datastax Spark Cassandra Connector that takes parameter `spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.keyStore.path` and looks for this path on executor nodes.